# Python SQLite: enforce UTF-8 encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, unicode, utf-8

I'm developing a cross-platform Python (3.7+) application, and I need to rely on sort order of TEXT columns in SQLite, meaning the comparison algorithm of TEXT values must be based on UTF-8 bytes. Even if the system encoding (`sys.getdefaultencoding()`) is not `utf-8`.

But in documentation of [sqlite3 module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) I can't find an encoding option for `sqlite3.connect`.

And I read that the use of `sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")` is an ugly hack and highly discouraged (that's why we need to `reload(sys)` before calling it)

So what's the solution?

Comment: UTF-8 is the default, but also https://www.sqlite.org/search?q=encoding&i=1 and https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_encoding

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thanks, I looked at Python's C code to make sure only one of these 2 functions are used.

Comment: Try to put a character outside your default encoding 9but in Unicode), and check if it get in sqlite, and if it sort. [Go to Wikipedia, select Japan, or a city (nearly every Asian cities/country works), you get also the UTF-8 string in original script of the name)]. Could you get it? So default encoding is not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at Python's [_sqlite/connection.c](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Modules/_sqlite/connection.c) code, either `sqlite3_open_v2` or `sqlite3_open` is called (depending on a compile flag). And based on [sqlite doc](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html), both of them use UTF-8 as default database encoding. I'm still not sure about the meaning of word "default" since it doesn't mention any way to override it! But I it doesn't look like that Python can open with another encoding.

```
#ifdef SQLITE_OPEN_URI
    Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
    rc = sqlite3_open_v2(database, &self->db,
                         SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE |
                         (uri ? SQLITE_OPEN_URI : 0), NULL);
#else
    if (uri) {
        PyErr_SetString(pysqlite_NotSupportedError, "URIs not supported");
        return -1;
    }
    Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
    rc = sqlite3_open(database, &self->db);
#endif
```